# VPN Server host name - public DNS resolution

Tags: security, vpn, dns

I have a VPN server which I have to configure in the next few days. One question that is tormenting me is which host name should I give it for public DNS resolution.

Will it be secure if I choose something as vpn.google.pt, or the "vpn" part will become a nice atractive catch for script kiddies out there?

Thanks

Comment: If your security is predicated on an obscure name, then you have none.

Comment: @paul Security through obscurity is bad to rely on, but that doesn't mean that obscurity doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to choose a name that reflects the purpose and content of the server.

Choosing "vpn" as a name will not affect security (See "security through obscurity").